# Replace all occurrences of \\ not starting with

Tags: php, regex, substring, backslash

This should be simple.  I want to change all of these substrings:

```
\\somedrive\some\path
```

into

```
file://\\somedrive\some\path
```

but if substrings already have a `file://` then I don't want to append it again.

This doesn't seem to do anything:

```
var_export( str_replace( '\\\\', 'file://\\\\', '\\somedrive\some\path file://\\somedrive\some\path' ) );
```

What am I doing wrong?  Also, the above doesn't take into test for `file://` already being there; what's the best way of dealing with this?

**UPDATE** test input:

```
$test = '
file://\\someserver\some\path

\\someotherserver\path
';
```

test output:

```
file://\\someserver\some\path

file://\\someotherserver\path
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider escape sequence in `string` also.

```
if((strpos($YOUR_STR, '\\\\') !== false) && (strpos($YOUR_STR, 'file://\\\\') === false))
    var_export( str_replace( '\\\\', 'file://\\\\', $YOUR_STR ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to check  if the given substring starts with `file://`. If it does, don't do anything. If it doesn't, append `file://` at the beginning of the string:

```
if (!preg_match("~^file://~i", $str)) {
    $str = 'file://' . $str;
}
```

As a function:

```
function convertPath($path) {
    if (!preg_match("~^file://~i", $path)) {
        return 'file://'.$path;
    }
    return $path;
}
```

Test cases:

```
echo convertPath('\\somedrive\some\path');
echo convertPath('file://\\somedrive\some\path');
```

Output:

```
file://\somedrive\some\path
file://\somedrive\some\path
```

Comment: Thanks but it's a single string with possibly many of these substrings.. some with `file://` already and some without.

Comment: @ale: It should work for both the cases. See the updated answer.

Comment: yeh but what if you had something like '\\somedrive\some\path file://\\somedrive\some\path' (in any order and any number)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
For multiple occurrences : `preg_replace('#((?!file://))\\\\#', '$1file://\\\\', $path)`

Answer (score 0):

This will work to give you the output you are expecting. As [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) says double slash will be converted into single slash.

```
if (!preg_match('/^file:\/\//', $str)) {
    $str =  "file://\\".stripslashes(addslashes($str));
}
```

Comment: Good point about the double slash conversion.  However, this solution doesn't cope with something like: `'\\somedrive\some\path file://\\somedrive\some\path' (in any order and any number)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$string = "\\somedrive\some\path";
$string = "\\".$string;
echo str_replace( '\\\\', 'file://\\\\',$string);
```

Comment: your `str_replace` would prepend `file://` again if `file://` was already there